# Python Selenium: driver.quit() failed to clear temporary file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler, selenium-ide

I'm running Selenium with Firefox browser driver on a Linux server. The root/tmp folder is kept flooding with temporary files generate by selenium, even though I have used driver.quit() after each driver call. Those temp files has names like tmp04kyw42n, Temp_xxx.

Here is my code:

```
opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_driver_path, options=opts)

driver.get(url)
...
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((...)).click()
...
driver.quit()
```

Are those temp files keep generating because of the click in the middle?

My environment:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Browser: Firefox
Browser version: 80
Browser Driver version: GeckoDriver 0.29
selenium package 3.8.0
```

Could anyone tell me how to stop generating those temp files in root/tmp, or how to redirect the location where those temporary file are generated to another folder? I'll consider the later one as a secondary but acceptable solution, because I can delete all content in the new tmp folder whenever I want. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to set up this preference `browser.cache.disk.parent_directory`

Comment: I think those would be created by Firefox.  Are they still there after a reboot?